# Relation between Electrostatic Field and Electrostatic Potential at infinite

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, voltage, conventions

While reading about Electrostatics Potential I had a question about the relation between electrostatic potential and electrostatic field. As we know that $E = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{Q}{r^2}$ and $V = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{Q}{r}$ and we also know that $dV = \vec{E}\cdot\vec{dr}.$ Now if we plot two curves $E$ vs $r$ and $V$ vs $r,$ we observe that $E$ vs $r$ curve approaches $0$ faster than the later one, hence we can say that at some point when $E$ becomes $0$, $V$ will not be $0$ and since $E = 0$ we can say that $dV = 0,$ hence electrostatic potential of an object is never $0,$ then why do we keep consider that $V = 0$ at infinite while solving problems and various derivations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*we observe that $E$ vs $r$ curve approaches $0$ faster than the later one, hence we can say that at some point when E becomes $0$, V will not be $0$* is a false statement.

Try with numbers and report back the value of $r$ when $E=0$.

It is difficult when talking about infinity but imagine two functions, $y=x$ and $y = 2x$ which pass through the origin.
In your terminology the value of one function, $y=2x$, "approaches zero faster" than the other $y=x$ but they still both reach zero when $x=0$.

Going back to electric field and electric potential.

Given that $E = -\frac{dV}{dr}$ you will note that to move towards zero $V$ must change and as long as $V$ is changing there is a value of $\frac{dV}{dr}$ and hence a value, not equal to zero, of $E$.